# Jimdo: Add placeholder to html using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Due to limitations of the webhoster "Jimdo" I can not change html document to insert a "placeholder" into a text field. Is there a way to add that attribute using javascript or jquery?

I have already tried a few codes that I found here but it did not work for me. Maybe I just put a bracket wrong or the code was not compatible with Jimdo's head-area...

This is the code from Jimdo.

```html
<input type="text" name="url" id="url9611056885" value="" class="single">
```

Screenshot:[image: Jimdo html code screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for jQuery, a plain `JavaScript` solution. A function that accept two arguments the first represent the element itself or a `string` representing its `ID`, and the second argument is the placeholder `string`:

```js
function addPlaceholder(el, ph) {
  if(typeof el === 'string') {
    el = document.getElementById(el);
  } else if(el instanceof HTMLElement === false) {
    console.log('Not a valid HTML element.');
    return false;
  }
  el.setAttribute('placeholder', ph);
  return true;
}
addPlaceholder('input1', "a placeholder for input 1"); // sending the ID of the input element
addPlaceholder(document.getElementById('input2'), "a placeholder for input 2"); // sending the input element itself
addPlaceholder(window, "will not work!"); // sending a non-valid HTML element here the window object, a log in the console will appear and the function returns false.
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
```

Comment: Maybe the id is not really linked to the input text field? I don't know. I tried everything but i won't work...

Comment: but in the snippet it's working ! what have you tried ? let me see your code.

Comment: Ja, every code works fine here but not in jimdo for me. Maybe i embed it wrong in the head area of jimdo. Missing brackets or something, i don't know. I tried every code with that id from the input text. Yours, everybody's.

Comment: the code I provided works perfectly. Can you give me a screenshot of your code where you put in jimbo etc... just upload a screenshot to a cloud and give me the link.

Comment: ja of course. [here](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/1G2e3C1j3u0x063M0F1v/screenshot.PNG)

Comment: I see. Try to put the function callls in `DOMContentLoaded` event listener like this: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {addPlaceholder('input1', "a placeholder for input 1"); // sending the ID of the input element
addPlaceholder(document.getElementById('input2'), "a placeholder for input 2"); // sending the input element itself
addPlaceholder(window, "will not work!"); // sending a non-valid HTML element here the window object, a log in the console will appear and the function returns false.});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178650/discussion-between-ths-and-janosch).

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```js
$("#url9611056885").attr("placeholder","I'm a placeholder");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="url" id="url9611056885" value="" class="single">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to do that.

```js
document.getElementById("url9611056885").setAttribute("placeholder", "Hey! I'm alive!");
```

```html
<input type="text" name="url" id="url9611056885" value="" class="single">
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript use the `setAttribute` method.

```
var element= document.getElementById("url9611056885");
element.setAttribute("placeholder", "SOME PLACEHOLDER");
```

In JQuery use `attr` method.

```
$("#url9611056885").attr("placeholder","SOME PLACEHOLDER");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may traverse in the `form` searching `label` having `for` attribute which will direct to target `input` and assign the inner `text` within `label` as placeholder to `input`.

```
$(function() {
  $('form').find('label[for]').each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this);
    var cnt = $('#' + lbl.prop('for'));
    if (cnt.is(":text") || cnt.is(":password") || cnt.is("textarea")) {
      cnt.prop('placeholder', lbl.text());
    }
  });
});
```

P.S. Make sure that you have imported jQuery in your page before above code snippet.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> I'm not into java or jquery and i have no idea what to do right now

You had `jQuery` tag in your post, hence I given solution based on that tag.

Comment: I tried every code above but it won't work. I would like to try your solution as well but I'm not into java or jquery and i have no idea what to do right now. Can you give me an example of how it should look like on my page?

Comment: I imported everything correctly but no code works for me. I know, normally it would have to work but maybe someone has the same problem with jimdo and it is because of jimdo?